# Cython wrap an opencv project

Tags: python, opencv, cython

I wrote a class which use OpenCV Library. These are the methods that I want to expose to Python:

```
class ACA()
{
    ACA();
    Mat getsegmentation(Mat in);
}
```

This is what I have written for the wrapper so far. How to convert between numpy array and opencv Mat object?

```
cdef extern from "aca.h":
    cdef cppclass ACA:
        ACA()
        aca_seg(Mat)

def aca(im):
    pass
    # lev=aca.aca_seg(m)
```

Comment: I have wanted a good explanation of this as well. There should be a conversion function somewhere (C-file) in the OpenCV source code that converts data from/to opencv/numpy, but I am not sure where it is, or how you most easily use it.

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/0a624ee67d110c47d7dcf0b57254ca87821b1cc5/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp#L178 Still no idea how you use it outside the OpenCV source tree though.